# Do I need to handle atomicity myself for LocalTargets?

Tags: python, luigi

The Luigi documentation describes [potential problems regarding atomicity](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/luigi_patterns.html#atomic-writes-problem) of writing to targets. They say that this is a common pitfall and that it should be handled using temporary directories that are moved to the target location in the end.

*Do I also need to handle this myself if my target is a single-file `LocalTarget`?*

The `luigi.local_target` module contains an `atomic_file` class, which seems to indicate that this is done automatically, and the design goals [include “atomic file system operations”](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/design_and_limitations.html). But I couldn't find any documentation stating that `LocalTarget` is safe to be used that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the code of Luigi luigi/local_target.py class LocalTarget:

```
def open(self, mode='r'):
    rwmode = mode.replace('b', '').replace('t', '')
    if rwmode == 'w':
        self.makedirs()
        return self.format.pipe_writer(atomic_file(self.path))
```

Luigi create a temporary file and when it's closed, changes to the final name.

Comment: Yes, this is where I looked as well; I had hoped, though, that this behavior is documented somewhere so I can rely on it staying that way.